# Ruby Torrent Library

Tags: ruby, bittorrent

Is there any good library for Ruby to work with BitTorrent trackers? To download or seed files. There's a rubytorrent library on rubyforge, but it was last updated in 2005 and doesn't seem like working anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see lib-torrent ruby... 
https://github.com/maran/libtorrent-ruby

I'm not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: This one is also haven't been updated for a long time. An archive is even damaged

Comment: you are right... It is newer then the other one though. I can't seem to find a proper one...

Answer (score 0):

Also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111517/ruby-bittorrent-library) which contains some potentially useful comments as well, including a Ruby wrapper for the Transmission API using RPCs.

My experience with libtorrent derived clients has been very positive, I would like to see something new here.  (I prefer the high density interface & advanced features of qbittorrent to the sparse UI of Transmission.)

A torrent client that exchanges DHT buckets to crawl the public DHT... ?

(No web searching required.)