# Ruby BitTorrent Library

Tags: ruby, bittorrent

I am thinking of writing customized torrent client in ruby. I found the following libraries (which are pretty old as Matt pointed out bellow). However i would like to hear about any library that i might have missed and i would love to hear what the community have to say about the following libraries. As in pros and cons...

- [RubyTorrent](http://rubytorrent.rubyforge.org/)
- [libtorrent-ruby](http://libtorrent-ruby.rubyforge.org/)

Please note that i am hoping to modify some inner workings of the library to suit my needs. Hence a pure ruby library would be ideal.

*Note: I searched stackoverflow for this question (or anything similar). The only questions that came up were asked long ago and didn't have any decent answers. Hence this new question.*

- [Ruby Torrent Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750358/ruby-torrent-library)

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Both of those projects are 5+ years old...

Comment: I know, its hopeless. There should be something out there thats maintained... right?

Comment: I guess there just isn't the demand for a Ruby implementation.

Comment: You may as well provide a link from this question to those questions, so that people who come across the old questions will know about this question (links get displayed both ways).

Comment: added a link to the old question

Comment: Any new information about this question?

Comment: @fguillen nope i've given up on it for the time being. but please do update up if you come across anything.

Comment: @thekindofme at the end I implemented a Ruby Wrapper for the Transmission API as you can see in my answer, at the end I think is better than a native Ruby bitttorrent implementation because I don't think any Ruby implementation was gonna be as active development as this bittorrent client. But I understand it is not covering your particular needs as you explain in your question.

Answer (score 3):

After not finding any good solution to connect my ruby code to a BitTorrent protocol I have implemented a Ruby wrapper for the Transmission RPC API:

- http://rubygems.org/gems/transmission_api

It is a very simple version that works for my needs.

Of course it has a very big dependency of a [Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) client running for it, but I think it is a dependency you want to have due it is a very stable and very updated bittorrent client.

I recommend to set up a [headless transmission daemon](http://www.geeklk.com/2012/08/setup-a-headless-transmission-client-in-ubuntu-12-04/)

Comment: @AbeVoelker it is the one I'm using in my desktop and it works like a charm, also I see the developers are very focused in simplicity and I like that. Anyhow I should check _rtorrent_ too.

Comment: @fguillen this is pretty neat. and you should checkout rtorrent. its one of the fastest and most stable clients out there. I think it already have many APIs in several languages including ruby. so you might want to check those out as well. ex: https://github.com/mcmorgan/retort

Answer (score 1):

You have a few alternatives, rolling your own with [FFI](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/wiki/) and any c/c++/java torrent library, or use a well known torrent daemon (ie: transmission, utorrent, etc) and talk to it via its rpc interface.